# Fetch data from database where logged in user id exist in an column that stores ids as an array Laravel 8

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the rows in a database where logged in user exists. Here is my structure

```
Table = Meetings
Column = Participants (stores an array of users eg.["1","2","3"]);
Auth()->id() = "1"
```

I want a query that will fetch rows if Auth()->id() exist in participants which stores an array of User id.

here is my code:

```
    $meetings = Meeting::join('venues', 'meetings.meeting_venue', '=', 'venues.id')                             
              ->join('organizers','meetings.meeting_organizer','=','organizers.id') 
              ->join('users', 'meetings.user_id','=','users.id')  
              ->where('meetings.participants', '=', auth()->id())                                                  
              ->get(['meetings.*', 'venues.venue_name', 'organizers.organizer_name','users.name', ]);
```

Here is my participants column from the database:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "participants" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "52"
      1 => "56"
      2 => "57"
    ]
  ]
]

$meetings = DB::table('meetings')->whereJsonContains('meetings.participants', auth()->id())->get()->toArray();
```

dump returns empty array.

Comment: Can you please share your actual **Participants** array? Because ```whereJsonContains()``` should work.

Comment: I have added the participants column which stores the array as a json column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way around it I assigned auth()->id() to a variable then added double quote in the query. Below is how I did it

```
$uid = auth()->id();
-> whereJsonContains('meetings.participants', "$uid");

this works fine
```

Comment: It's the concept of **Type Juggling** (Type Casting) in PHP. You can use as ```(string) $uid```. It's a more readable form.

Comment: okay will get on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick, here it is:

```
$meetings = Meeting::join('venues', 'meetings.meeting_venue', '=', 'venues.id')                             
          ->join('organizers','meetings.meeting_organizer','=','organizers.id') 
          ->join('users', 'meetings.user_id','=','users.id')  
          ->where('meetings.participants', 'like', "%\"{auth()->id()}\"%")
          ->get(['meetings.*', 'venues.venue_name', 'organizers.organizer_name','users.name']);
```

or You can use whereJsonContains(), like so:

```
 $meetings = Meeting::join('venues', 'meetings.meeting_venue', '=', 'venues.id')
     ->join('organizers','meetings.meeting_organizer','=','organizers.id') 
     ->join('users', 'meetings.user_id','=','users.id')  
     -> whereJsonContains('meetings.participants', "'".auth()->id()."'")
     ->get(['meetings.*', 'venues.venue_name', 'organizers.organizer_name','users.name']);
```

Hope this helps you. Greetings

Comment: this returns nothing.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1403 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

Comment: Should add quote around auth()->id(). See correction below